# Dynamically rotate buttons in landscape view

Tags: android, view

I am working with OpenCV in android. I am forced to use

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml

The problem I am facing is that I want to rotate only one Button according to screen orientation. The rest must remain un rotated.

Is that possible?
Will the line I added to Manifest File prevent detection of all future rotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide layout for that.

for Example.

```
res
    layout
        main.xml
    layout-land
        main.xml
```

Now create your layout you want under `-land` folder. And it will load when phone is rotate.

Feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the line added prevent all rotations.

You can create a new folder under /res , called 'layout-land' (without quotes), copy your layout to these folder and modify. Android read layout folder to protait orientation, and layout-land to show the layout landscape orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the Position Sensor as described in this article ([Position Sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html)) to determine the orientation of your phone.

With that, you can get the angle in onSensorChanged() as following.

```
@Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float azimuth_angle = event.values[0];
    float pitch_angle = event.values[1];
    float roll_angle = event.values[2];
    // Do something with these orientation angles.
  }
```

Hope this helps.